# Prevent admin url from being overridden Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a urls file that looks like this, however I cannot access the admin page. Is there any way to specify that the admin URL should never be overridden?

````
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from latency import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("<str:chain>", views.regions),
    path("<str:chain>/<str:region>", views.chain),
    path("", views.index),
]```
````

Comment: What do you mean by *"can't access the URL"*?

Comment: @JPG when I go to <my_site>/admin, instead of bringing up the admin panel it forwards me to views.region, with the "chain" parameter being "admin".

Comment: maybe you should try with `/admin/` (ends with a *"slash"*) instead of `/admin`